# Using resultant vectors to calculate how long it takes to travel a distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, kinematics, friction, vectors

> A box of books weighing $320 \;\mathrm{N}$ is shoved across the floor of an apartment by a force of $569 \;\mathrm{N}$ exerted downward at an angle of $36.5^\circ$ below the horizontal. The acceleration of gravity is $9.8\;\mathrm{m/s^2}$. If the coefficient of kinetic friction between box and floor is $0.514$, how long does it take to move the box $7.47 \;\mathrm{m}$, starting from rest?

What I have done is to add the $569 \;\mathrm{N}$ vector with $\mu_kn$ and finding the horizontal component of that resultant vector. Then I divide that by the mass to find the acceleration of the box and use $s=ut+\frac12at^2$ to  find the time, but I get an incorrect answer. **Is this a good way to approach this problem? If not, could you point me in the right direction or give me a hint?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I have done is to add the $569\;\mathrm{N}$ vector with $μ_kn$ and finding the horizontal component of that resultant vector.

Something's wrong here. The resultant force vector should not have any other components than the horizontal one - otherwise the object should be moving vertically also, which it doesn't.

In the sentence here it seems that you are not adding the weight vector of the $320\;\mathrm{N}$ point downwards. You must add this vector also, so all force vectors are summed before finding the resultant force vector.

Alternatively, you can choose to look in just *one* direction. The horizontal direction would be smart to choose, since the acceleration is in that direction, which means that all vertical components and forces are cancelling out to zero. For the horizontal forces, you should add the friction $\mu_kn$ (with a minus in front! Remember that) to the *horizontal component* of the $569\;\mathrm{N}$:

$$569\;\mathrm{N}*\cos(36.5)^\circ -\mu_kn=ma$$

Comment: Isn't the weight balanced by the normal force?

Comment: No, it is balanced by the normal force *and* the vertical part of the pushing force. See the addition I added to the answer.

Comment: I see this type of error frequently in my high school physics classes.  Normal force is only equal to weight if there are no vertical components of force pushing down or pulling up on an object.  To properly calculate normal force, I suggest that you ALWAYS draw a free-body diagram, and set up and solve the summation of forces in the vertical direction (where vertical is normal to the surface that the object is on).

Comment: @DavidWhite ok, I think I understand now. I will be sure to take your advice in the future.